# Secret updates?

Tags: updates

When there's an Ubuntu update, I get a popup notification that tells what is being updated with the ability to get more specific information on what is being updated. Every once in a while, I get the popup but there is nothing in the description that gives any info other than this:[image: Updater Screen]

So is this a CIA plot, a Russian or North Korean hack or just a plain, boring bug?I am currently running 18.04 but also saw it on 17.10.

Comment: It is more than likely a bug.  If you go to a terminal window and run the `sudo apt update` then run the `apt list --upgradeable` it will probably show you what is available for the upgrade right now.

Comment: All of them are bionic-updates, bionic-security. 6 million dollar man stuff.